# perl6 Permutation match

Tags: match, permutation, raku

I am still trying to work on permutation match, and I wonder if anyone has better way to do it. I want to match all patterns in an array in any order, i.e., match permutations of items (string or other objects) in an array. E.g., if array is (1,2,3), then it is true if a string contains 1 and 2 and 3 in any order; i.e, true if a string contains permutation of (1,2,3).

What I have now is this:

```
my @x = < one eins uno yi two zwei dos er one one one two two two >;
my @z = < one eins uno yi two zwei dos er one one one two two two foo >;
my $y = "xxx one eins uno yi two zwei dos er xxx";

sub matchAllWords($aString, @anArray) {
    my $arraySize = @anArray.elems;
    if $arraySize == 0 { False; }
    elsif $arraySize == 1 { 
    ($aString.match(/:i "@anArray[0]" /)).Bool; 
    } else { 
    my $firstCheck = ($aString.match(/:i "@anArray[0]"/)).Bool;
    if $firstCheck {
        $firstCheck
        and
        (matchAllWords($aString, @anArray[1..*])); 
    } else {
        return False;
    }
  }
}

say matchAllWords($y, @x); 
# result is True, but it should NOT be True because $y should not 
# match permutations of @x which contains multiple identical elements
# of "one" and "two"
say matchAllWords($y, @z); # False as expected;
```

The problems is that my function matches all unique words in the array, but is unable to differentiate permutations of duplicate words. I can add more and more codes to tell if a word has been matched, but more codes to accomplish a simple idea, "permutation match", is un-perl-ly. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to check if every element that is contained in the Array `n` times, also appears in the string exactly `n` times? Or something else?

Comment: Have you looked and `Bag`s and set operators?  It feels like you want to compare two Bags in some way (identity / subset).  Is that what you want?

Comment: Couldn't you just sort both lists?

Comment: Thank you smls, Elizabeth, and Brad ! Sorry for not being clear. Here is an example of what I want to achieve. Say, I have a string $x="a1bb3dd2xyz"; I want to know if $x will match a permutation of an array of strings. If my array @a = <1 a 2 2>, then any strings that contain "1", "a", and TWO "2"s will match; $x will not match; "xx22yy1wwa" and "wwayy2zz2mm1" should match, but "xx2y1wa" should not because it has only one "2", and "z12bba1" should not because it has extra "1". So, it is not exactly like Bag. What smls said is close to what I want to do. Thank you all very much !!

Comment: Sorry, a clarification to my comment above. "z12bba1" should not because it has extra "1" and missing one "2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New answer**

Based on everyone's comments, here's a restatement of the problem as I now understand it, followed by a new solution:

Test that `Y`, a string, contains all of the strings in `Z`, a [Bag](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Bag) ([multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)) of strings, with correct copy count / multiplicity.

```
my \Z = < one eins uno yi two zwei dos er two > .Bag ;

my \Y = "xxx one eins uno yi two zwei dos er two xxx" ;

sub string-matches-bag ($string, $bag) {
    for $bag.kv -> $sub-string, $copy-count {
        fail unless ($string ~~ m:g/ $sub-string /).elems == $copy-count
    }
    True
}

say string-matches-bag Y, Z
```

---

**Old answer**

```
say so $y.words.all eq @z.any
```

An explanation for this line of code is in the last part of this answer.

---

I found your question pretty confusing. But I'm hopeful this answer is either what you want or at least enough to move things in the right direction.

I found your data confusing. There are two `'xxx'` words in your `$y` but none in either array. So that bit can't match. There's a `'foo'` in your `@z`. Was that supposed to be `'xxx'`? There's a `'one'` in your `$y` but both arrays have at least *two* `'one'`s. Is that an issue?

I found your narrative confusing too.

For this answer I've assumed that `@z` has a `xxx` at the end, and that the key comment is:

> a simple idea, "permutation match"

---

```
say so $y.words.all eq @z.any
```

`so` returns the boolean evaluation (`True` or `False`) of the expression on its right.

The expression on `so`'s right uses [Junctions](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junction). An English prose summary of it is 'all of the "words" in `$y`, taken one at a time, are string equal to at least one element of `@z`'.

Is this the simple solution you're asking for?

Comment: Thank you raiph !! Sorry for being confusing. Let me re-phrase my question: Does this string match any of the permutations of an array of words? E.g., if string is "1a2", and the array is <1,1,a,2>, then it will not match because all permutations of the array have two "1"s. String "x1y2zab1" should match because it contains a permutation of the array. I am thinking about this: say so $y ~~ m/ <{ EVAL @a.permutations.one }> / but this is not working yet and I personally don't like to EVAL because using EVAL means I am lacking expressivity and clarity in my code. Thanks !!!

Comment: I hope perl6 can add such a permutation match to its base match utilities. The real world application that I  have to solve is this. Each line of a file has some important words in any order and the word may or may not be separated by spaces, and I know only parts of some of the words, and I want lines that contain these parts of words. Thanks !

Comment: Great !!! Thank you very much raiph !!! Bag, :g match with element counts were a neat idea. I am very happy to live in a world where most people are smarter and more knowledgeable than I am :-)